# Android 11 - Saving a .csv Log File to a Location that the User can Reliably Access Using Windows File Explorer

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an application in Kotlin for Android 11.  My app collects a log of sailing data from the boat instruments and internal GPS during a race.

I want to write a .csv file to some location where the User can access this using Windows File Explorer (connecting to the Android device with a USB cable) to copy and analyse the data in Windows.

I have been able to create and write .csv files to a subdirectory of Documents however if the User deletes the file using FileExplorer then Android 11 still reports that the file exists { filename.exists() returns true } when it doesn't, but worse won't delete what it thinks exists using { filename.delete() },  returns false for { filename.CanWrite() }, fails (returns false) to execute { filename.createNewFile()}  and crashes if I try and write anything to the file.

How can I reliably provide the logged data to a User ???
Very happy to use any alternative approach that can get the log data to the User and not be damaged by File Explorer actions.

I successfully obtained User permission to write files to a subdirectory under Documents /storage/emulated/0/Documents/layline

The path to the Documents folder was obtained from:
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

The Manifest contains:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

and I successfully verified the permissions with:
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) retuns 0
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) returns 0

I was able to read and write to a file OK until the file was deleted using Windows File Explorer.
The files are Read Only from Windows perspective and if the file is edited and saved to a separate location and then copied back to overwrite the original, the file system starts presenting [1], [2] etc suffixes and Android 11 can't seem to get back at the file (it thinks that a version exists but can't delete or write to it).

Uninstalling and reinstalling the app does not fix the problem.  Android 11 still reports that the file exists, but can't write to it.
filename.SetWritable() does not help (returns false).

Do I need to use All Files Access or Manage External Storage ?

Comment: Use the Storage Access Framework, such as `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument`. This allows the *user* to decide where on the *user's* device that your app should store the *user's* data.

Comment: If you delete a file from Documents directory and you cannot create a new one because Android tells you that the file still exists then you have to delete the entry in the MediaStore first as apparently the file has been scanned/indexed by it.

Comment: Further you could decide not to let the file be deleted by external means. Then you can just overwrite it. Further you could create logfiles with date-time in the file name. And start a new file every day.

Comment: I reread your post again. The solution is to simply add a day-time to your tracklog file. Every track logger does that.

Comment: And directly write all in a .gpx file ;-).

Comment: Many thanks for the responses.  My original design was to have User parameter files (waypoints, course, polars etc) and log files stored in a shared directory that the User could easily access using File Explorer in order to be able to easily change these out for different situations.
The SAF seems the safest approach to use, is clearly where Google is directing developers and is likely to best survive future Android versions.  However it would be unacceptable for the User to need to point to the directory or files each time the app is used.

Comment: So I have restructured to use SAF with the User initiating importing and exporting of files when required.  The imported files are either stored in internal storage or else directly in databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As posted by @blackapps:
If you delete a file from Documents directory and you cannot create a new one because Android tells you that the file still exists, then you have to delete the entry in the MediaStore first as apparently the file has been scanned/indexed by it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store your log files in `/data/data/{your package name}/caches` and then write to `/storage/emulated/0/layline` via Documents when users need to get log files